# Is it possible to display the amount of users who have rated a list item?

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, spservices, content-query-web-part

1. I'm using a list with the default SP rating columns
2. I'm displaying the ratings on the front end through my XSLT
3. SPServices is used to hover over the rating images and write back to the list item when a user clicks a start
4. I only have front end access

Is it possible to display how many times this list item has been rated and present it as a number on the front end? For example..."25 people have rated this product"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If haven't been clear on any of the steps, please let me know and I'll elaborate the best I can.

Answer (score 0):

[This site](http://habaneroconsulting.com/blog/posts/Calling_the_Rating_Service_using_jQuery_in_SharePoint_2010_Part_1_of_2.aspx#.UaVuQ0DVB8E) details how to use the SharePoint social web service to retrieve social information about a list.  Hopefully, this will point you in the right direction.